# Using Bound with multiple type variables for abstractions

Tags: haskell, monads

I've been trying out the [bound](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.17/bound-2.0.1/Bound.html) package - one toy example you can try this with is System F. Unlike the examples in the package documentation which have one type parameter for the variable being bound by a lambda, System F will have two type parameters, one for ordinary variables (bound by an ordinary lambda abstraction) and one for type variables (bound by type abstractions).

I don't quite understand how to use the package, but looking at the examples, the impression I get is that I should start with writing a `Monad` instance for an expression type. However, I ran into trouble, as I am not able to come up with something that typechecks and is also "obviously correct" (i.e. seems intuitively correct by inspection). So far I have

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

module SystemF where

import Bound
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bifunctor

-- e ::= x | λx : τ. e | e1 e2 | ΛX. e | e [τ]
-- t denotes type variables, e denotes expression variables
data Exp t e
  = Var e
  | Lam (Scope () (Exp t) e)
  | App (Exp t e) (Exp t e)
  | TyLam (Scope () (FlipExp e) t) -- Is this correct?
  | TyApp (Exp t e) (Type t)

newtype FlipExp e t = FlipExp { getExp :: Exp t e }

instance Functor (Exp t) where
  fmap = second

instance Bifunctor Exp where
  bimap f g = \case
    Var e -> Var (g e)
    Lam s -> Lam (bimapInScope f g s)
    App e1 e2 -> App (bimap f g e1) (bimap f g e2)
    TyLam s' -> TyLam (bimapInScope g f s')
    TyApp e t -> TyApp (bimap f g e) (fmap f t)
    where
      bimapInScope f g = Scope . bimap f (second (bimap f g)) . unscope

instance Applicative (Exp t) where
  pure = Var
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (Exp t) where
  x >>= f = case x of
    Var v -> f v
    Lam s -> Lam (s >>>= f)
    App e1 e2 -> App (e1 >>= f) (e2 >>= f)
    TyLam s ->
      -- tmp :: Exp (Var () (Exp t a) a
      -- but we need Exp (Var () (Exp t b)) b
      -- just applying >>= inside the first argument 
      -- is insufficient as the outer 'a' won't change
      let tmp = first (second getExp) $ getExp (unscope s)
      in error "How do I implement this?"
    TyApp e t -> TyApp (e >>= f) t

instance Functor (FlipExp e) where
  fmap = second

instance Bifunctor FlipExp where
  bimap f g = FlipExp . bimap g f . getExp

-- τ ::= X | τ -> τ | ∀ X . τ
data Type t
  = TVar t
  | TFun (Type t) (Type t)
  | TForall (Scope () Type t)
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Applicative Type where
  pure = TVar
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Type where
  x >>= f = case x of
    TVar v -> f v
    TFun t1 t2 -> TFun (t1 >>= f) (t2 >>= f)
    TForall s -> TForall (s >>>= f)
```

1. Is it possible to have a monad instance for `Exp t`? If yes, how?
2. What is the intuition behind the Monad instance? For the State/Maybe monads, I've found it useful to think of them as chaining computations (in terms of bind), whereas for structures like Lists, I've found it useful to think in terms of flattening (in terms of join). However, I am unable to come up with any proper intuition for the Monad instance for Exp. Does bind precisely do capture-avoiding substitution? I read through this [post](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound) but got lost after the ordinary "De Bruijn indices" section.

Comment: I am not familiar with bound, but I find `TyLam (Scope () (FlipExp e) t)` a bit strange. I would have expected something like `TyLam (Scope () Type t)` instead, since one substitutes type variables with (open) types, not terms. (Again, it's possible that my intuition is misleading, and that your is indeed the right way to use bound.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure either what it should be (edited the question to include that) but if it is `Scope () Type t` then that would be very much like the `TForall` term despite the fact that they're different in the language syntax: `Λ X . e` (bind a type variable in an expression) vs `∀ X . τ` (bind a type variable in a type).

Comment: Yes, you are right. One needs to specify that there is a term after the binder, not a type. Then, maybe your original `FlipExp e` is correct. What puzzles me is that the variable X in `Λ X . e` does not bind to terms, but to types (even if `e` is a term). I wonder what would be the correct `Scope` for that (binder with a type variable, but constructing a term). I need to understand `bound` better.

Comment: About `Scope () (FlipExp e) t`: by definition of `Scope`, that is isomorphic to `FlipExp e (Var () (FlipExp e t))` which means `Exp (Var () (Exp t e)) e`. This looks wrong, since it allows to replace a type variable with an expression -- it should have been, I think, `Exp (Var () (Type t)) e`. I'm slowly starting to believe that `Scope` does not support expressions in `Exp` with binders binding in other types `Type`. `Scope b f a ~~ f (Var b (f a))` is not general enough, we need (I think) something like `Scope b f g a ~ f (Var b (g a))` so that we can use `Scope () (FlipExp e) Type t`

Comment: Indeed, `Scope () (FlipExp e) Type t ~ FlipExp e (Var () (Type t)) ~ Exp (Var () (Type t)) e` looks right to me. I have no idea, though, if this generalized `Scope` would work in practice, i.e. if we can successfully rewrite the `bound` package to include such an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/ekmett/bound/issues/72) and @phadej's [`bound-extras` package here](https://github.com/phadej/bound-extras/blob/5a0c264fc8e3481e4aae3e05cdc3fa526f0d53cc/examples/SystemF.hs).

The gist is that type abstraction is a term-level thing (so a variant of `Expr`) that needs to abstract over `Type`s. Plain `Scope b f a` is unsuited to deal with this, as its expansion `f (Either b (f a))` has `f` fixed for both occurrences. You want the outer `f` be an `Expr`, while the inner should be a `Type`. That leads to the following generalisations of `Scope`:

```
newtype ScopeH b f g a = ScopeH (g (Either b (f a)))
newtype ScopeT b t f a = ScopeT (t f (Either b (f a)))

newtype Expr' a b = Expr' (Expr b a)
data Expr b a
  = V a
  ...
  | TyApp (Expr b a) (Ty b)
  | Forall (ScopeH () (Expr' a) Ty b)
  ...
```

`Expr' a` fixes the de Bruijn index for term vars, so that the `ScopeH` constructor can introduce an additional type var to be put in `b` holes.